# Is it possible to use WHERE with ANY and ARRAY together?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called 'reviews' that I want to start the data cleaning process, so I want to find out if there are any records that have any NULL columns (there are 6 columns in the table).

So, instead of using the code below:

```
SELECT *  
FROM reviews  
WHERE listing_id IS NULL  
    OR id IS NULL  
    OR date IS NULL  
    OR reviewer_id IS NULL  
    OR reviewer_name IS NULL  
    OR comments IS NULL  

'''
```

I would like to simplify the code, using something like this:

```
SELECT *  
FROM reviews  
WHERE ANY( ARRAY [listing_id, id, date, reviewer_id, reviewer_name, comments]) IS NULL
```

But It doesn't work.

1. What's wrong with the second code?
2. Are there other more efficient ways to check?

Answer (score 4):

you can use [num_nulls()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-FUNC-TABLE)

```
where num_nulls(listing_id, id, date, reviewer_id, reviewer_name, comments) > 0
```